# How to recreate list like this in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, user-interface

How to recreate list like in new project window in visual studio with icon and text using windows forms?

Like this:
[image: New project in Visual studio]

Comment: you can use list view, here's a quick example [click me](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/9f4ff8/listview-in-C-Sharp/) or datagridview

Comment: Nope I mean create list like in new project window not new item in new project...

Comment: Sorry I don't quite get you what do you mean "list like"

Comment: I mean how to make something similar to use in my app?

Comment: Visual Studio IDE is written in WPF, so you might consider that for your project type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using **WPF** then it's quite easy because it provide great support for customization of it's controls

For more information and a good example [go here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/listbox-in-wpf/).

If you are using **Win forms** then it's quite tricky because you will have to create a new custom control for that to suite your needs, Your control could inherit from any list control and can represent a UI that you need using paint and/or dynamic control generation.

To see a good example of custom controls [go here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CCS-LABS-Windows-Forms-dcae8214)